# sys/resource.h in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm currenty trying to make some source code written in linux C++ in windows using cygwin, and keep getting error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory

Is there any package in cygwin that include sys/resource.h? if so what package?

I've tried googling it but haven't found anything yet, thx for your help

Answer (score 7):

sys/resource.h belongs to the cygwin package itself.

```
$ cygcheck -l cygwin | grep resource.h
/usr/include/sys/resource.h
```

If you got cygwin, then you must surely have sys/resource.h

Comment: Correct. Note besides, packages can also be searched at http://cygwin.com/packages.

Comment: @ak2, thanks for the tip on the package viewer at the URL you provided. Great to know!

Comment: Thx for your reply. I've tried the command above and found the resource.h at the location mentioned, but the make command still can't find the resource.h. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ndriks, you might want to specify what you are trying to make, or perhaps show the Makefile. Normally, I would expect that you don't need to specify anything special for includes, etc., to find that sys/resource.h  file. Maybe you could open up a new question, and give more concrete details on your Makefile?

Comment: Ok I will, but I think I will google some more first. Thx anyone for your help, much appreciated

Comment: I have a clean Cygwin installation, and it doesn't have a resource.h file... Tried searching through windows, and through Cygwin. Nothing.

Comment: @Wouter: I had the same problem, but by following @ak2's tip, I found it in the package `cygwin-devel`. Hope it helps.